# how to use the table function file in clickhouse?

Tags: function, file, templates, clickhouse

I am trying to use the table function file in clickhouse and below are what I have tried.

The background:
test sql:

```sql
create table test(a String,b Int32) ENGINE = Memory;--File(CSV)
insert into test (a,b) values ('world',22) ('quant',33);
insert into test (a,b) values ('hello',1);
select * from test;
SELECT a,b FROM test FORMAT Template SETTINGS format_template_resultset = '/home/resultset.format', format_template_row = '/home/row.format', format_template_rows_between_delimiter = '\n';
```

print:

```
head
the first:"world",the second:22;
the first:"quant",the second:33;

the first:"hello",the second:1;
end
```

the fail sql:

```sql
SELECT * FROM file("data",Template SETTINGS format_template_resultset = '/home/resultset.format', format_template_row = '/home/row.format', format_template_rows_between_delimiter = '\n', 'a String, b Int32');
```

print:

```
Syntax error: failed at position 36 ('SETTINGS'):

SELECT * FROM file("data",Template SETTINGS format_template_resultset = '/home/resultset.format', format_template_row = '/home/row.format', format_template_rows_between_delimiter = '\n', 'a String, b Int32');    

Expected one of: DoubleColon, LIKE, GLOBAL NOT IN, end of query, AS, DIV, IS, UUID, OR, QuestionMark, BETWEEN, NOT LIKE, MOD, AND, Comma, alias, IN, ILIKE, Dot, NOT ILIKE, NOT, Arrow, token, NOT IN, GLOBAL IN
```

I have checked the documentation but it does not seems to be correct. How can I achieve this?

Comment: it looks like the query is not valid - try this one: *SELECT * FROM file("data",Template, 'a String, b Int32') SETTINGS format_template_resultset = '/home/resultset.format', format_template_row = '/home/row.format', format_template_rows_between_delimiter = '\n';*

Answer (score 0):

@vladimir s answer is correct,

```sql
SELECT * FROM file("data",Template, 'a String, b Int32') SETTINGS format_template_resultset = '/home/resultset.format', format_template_row = '/home/row.format', format_template_rows_between_delimiter = '\n';
```

thank you.